Не проходит перевод на другой кошелек Phantom
Не проходит перевод соланы на другой кошелек.
Начинается отправка-
https://skr.sh/sQJ1UWQZqA8
и потом не получается((-
https://skr.sh/sQJ4cpf7jOy
Транзации тоже не видно((-
https://solscan.io/tx/3J22Zc1cFjnYZEQYC6S2WFuqticSJiVCCCqenbXrEVdtp7mDxyg8PCXNfeo6cJXtpdTEFZHmqqsQ4Z4zGSCpvSCk
Что не так??
Помогите пожалуйста!

I’m voting to close this question because its not in english

failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees
